# Power Query: replace null values if values of another column

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm working with a table that contains three columns: Number ID, Country, and State. In some rows, I have null values in the [Country] column, but there is data for the [State] column. I would like to replace these null values conditionally. For example if, "null" and [State] = California then "USA" but without adding a new conditional column 'cuase my model of data is already quite large. Is there any possibility?
Thank you
xo

I knew that there's a possibility of doing this with adding a ConditionalColumn but I would like to know if there's otherway

Comment: Everything you need is here: https://gorilla.bi/power-query/replace-values/

Comment: If you want more specific help, show some sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
Table.Transform(
#'Previous Step',
each [Country],
each if [Country] = null and [State] = "California" then "USA" else [Country],
Replacer.ReplaceText,
{"Country"}
)
```

However, This is going to be a lot to list out each state. My recommendation is to maintain a list of states and their country. From there, import this list. Use this code to convert that list into a function.

```
(State as text) =>
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="CountryLookup"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"State/Provice", type text}, {"Country", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([#"State/Provice"] = State)),
    Country = #"Filtered Rows"{0}[Country]
in
    Country
```

You will need to Modify the Source and maybe even the column names. This code works by establishing a connection to a list of known state/country codes. It filters the list to the selected state, then selects the country associated with it. Make sure your list does not contain duplicates! Name the query CountryLookup.

Now you can use that function to replace null values in your country field and reference the list.

```
Table.Transform(
#'Previous Step',
each [Country],
each if [Country] = null then CountryLookup([State]) else [Country],
Replacer.ReplaceText,
{"Country"}
)
```

This should "attempt" to replace any null values in your Country column without having to create a new column. It will still return null if your state doesn't exist or doesn't match. But if that's true, you can add the item not matching to your list and refresh the report.